# Google Drive API & Google Realtime API - Can I place a realtime file in the app folder?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Using the Google Drive API and Google Realtime API (via JavaScript):

I can create a realtime file without providing a parent. However when I attempt to set the parent as "[appdata](https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata)" I receive this error from the API:

> Only folders or files with content stored in Drive are allowed within
>   the appdata folder

It's a little vague perhaps a realtime file is not considered having contents?

So my question: Is it possible to place a realtime file within the app folder?

Comment: What are you trying to use this for?  Keep in mind that things in the app data folder can't be shared, so it probably doesn't make sense for a collaborative document..

Comment: I've got a realtime application that is only intend for a single user (on multiple devices) and as the contents is private I would like to be able to place it within the appdata folder so other apps cannot read the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through further investigation I have managed to find the answer to my question.

> Actually, unfortunately you cannot currently place a realtime file
>   within the appdata folder.  This is something we are looking at
>   adding, but in most cases it doesn't make sense since the content of
>   the appdata folder is restricted to a single user.

Cheryl Simon on Google Drive Developers - https://plus.google.com/communities/107264319205603895037

Comment: Google has since updated the Realtime API. You can now use load or loadAppDataDocument https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime#gapi.drive.realtime.loadAppDataDocument